# How to create sharp edge on the middle of UIView in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple images. when user select on a particular images i have to highlight that image with a view which has an arrow on the on the top. It will be solved simply by using an image which have sharp arrow edge on the top but i want to achieve using a uiview.
How to create a sharp arrow edge on the top middle of `UIView` using core graphics in iPhone. like the popover sharp arrow edge in iPad.

can any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give an example image and explain why you can't use third-party solutions on github.

Comment: i have not enough reputations to post image..

Comment: i don't understand why i'm getting downvotes...if my question is not good then suggest me..please do not downvote for my question...Thank you..

Comment: Because your question is unclear and seems to be of low quality.

Comment: Thank you @Divyu..Actually i suposed to post an image regarding my question.But there is a problem with posting image due to low reputations..Thank you once again.

Comment: @Venki The downvotes reflect the fact that your question looks a little... lazy. You should describe your problem in detail, how you tried to solve it, why that didn't work and why other people's suggested solutions are not suitable for your project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using UIView. Create a path as you want using [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/)

Then add the path to the graphics context and fill it will colour you want.

**Sample code will looks like this :**

```
#define kArrowHeight 50   

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIBezierPath *fillPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [fillPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.origin.y+kArrowHeight)];
    [fillPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2-(kArrowHeight/2), kArrowHeight)];
    [fillPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, 0)];
    [fillPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2+(kArrowHeight/2), kArrowHeight)];
    [fillPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, kArrowHeight)];
    [fillPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
    [fillPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.size.height)];
    [fillPath closePath];

    CGContextAddPath(context, fillPath.CGPath);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

}
```

Above code will give you a view which contain sharp edge on the middle of UIView which looks like popover, which looks like below.

[image]

**Please note:**

- You can change the path as per your requirement.
- Background colour of view should be  clear colour.

Comment: How would you recommend calling the draw rect? Would you call it in ViewDidLoad and pass in the view's frame?

Comment: You do not need to explicitly call draw rect method.

Comment: can you help me, How to draw it with down arrow..??

Comment: You just need to change the points and play around with the bezierpath.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one its really interesting
https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover,
https://github.com/runway20/PopoverView

Comment: Thank you...I know that popover..But i want to make it possible using uiview using core graphics not using popovers..

Answer (score 0):

If its app for iPad them you can use uipopovercontroller. Else for iphone u can find various controls on github

Comment: Thank you..But i have to use  a uiview rather than popovers..

Comment: Then us TSpopover control from github

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIView as container, and set the UIView background transparent. Next, add a sub-UIView to the container, and a arrow(UIImageView) at the top edge.

Comment: Thank you..But i have to use a single uiview...i think it may be possible using coregraphics..but i'm not getting how to use coregraphics to get such output..