# Objective-c : Designing UIView/UILabel Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I want to design an `UIView`/`UILabel` like this image programmatically in **objective c**. Specially the edge in the middle . Can anyone help ?

[image]

Currently I have :

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.tabPosition.x,self.tabPosition.y,120,20)]; //or whatever size you need
            myLabel.center = self.tabPosition;
            [myLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            myLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6f];
            myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",data.user.firstName,data.user.lastName] ;
            myLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
            myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self
                                               action:@selector(labelDragged:)] ;
            [myLabel addGestureRecognizer:gesture];


            [self.picture addSubview:myLabel];
```

Which giving me :
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: will your edge be always in middle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of answers already available, choose which fits you:

[basic and simplest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910575/how-to-create-sharp-edge-on-the-middle-of-uiview-in-iphone)

[arrow and round corner](https://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/03/09/rounded-corners-with-an-arrow-on-a-uiview-with-the-iphone-sdk-3-0/)

[creative solution](http://nfarina.com/post/29883229869/callout-view)

Hope these will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

You need one small image like u give sample.

Set stretch property of UIImageview so it will set as per you Text size and edge will stay in middle ([refer this link](http://macoscope.com/blog/stretchable-images-using-interface-builder/))